# How to validate a json schema against the version spec it specifies in Java

Tags: java, json, schema

Given a json schema like this..

```
    {
   "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
   "title": "Product",
   "description": "A product from Acme's catalog",
   "type": "object",

   "properties": {

      "id": {
         "description": "The unique identifier for a product",
         "type": "integer"
      },

      "name": {
         "description": "Name of the product",
         "type": "string"
      },

      "price": {
         "type": "number",
         "minimum": 0,
         "exclusiveMinimum": true
      }
   },

   "required": ["id", "name", "price"]
}
```

How to validate that this json schema conforms to the $schema it specifies, in this case the draft-04..

Are there any packages in java that can do this?
Can I use something like https://github.com/everit-org/json-schema or is that only validating a json document against its schema?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The schema linked from every JSON schema is in fact a sort of "meta-schema" for JSON schemas, so you can in fact use it to validate a schema as you suggest.

Suppose we have saved the meta-schema as a file called `meta-schema.json`, and our potential schema as `schema.json`. First we need a way to load these files as `JSONObjects`:

```
public static JSONObject loadJsonFromFile(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Reader reader = new FileReader(fileName);
    return new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(reader));
}
```

We can load the meta-schema, and load it into the json-schema library you linked:

```
JSONObject metaSchemaJson = loadJsonFromFile("meta-schema.json");
Schema metaSchema = SchemaLoader.load(metaSchemaJson);
```

Finally, we load the potential schema and validate it using the meta-schema:

```
JSONObject schemaJson = loadJsonFromFile("schema.json");
try {
    metaSchema.validate(schemaJson);
    System.out.println("Schema is valid!");
} catch (ValidationException e) {
    System.out.println("Schema is invalid! " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Given the example you posted, this prints "Schema is valid!". But if we were to introduce an error, for example by changing the `"type"` of the `"name"` field to `"foo"` instead of `"string"`, we would get the following error:

```
Schema is invalid! #/properties/name/type: #: no subschema matched out of the total 2 subschemas
```