# Seggregation of Json Schema Validation and Json Validation

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator, json-schema-defaults

I have a use case where I will take a json-schema as input, validate it, then keep in my system. Later I will get json data which I need to validate with above mentioned json-schema. given the scenario, I need to do two level of validations:

```
1. provided json-schema is valid or not.
2. Json is valid or not.
```

I am using json-schema-validator jar and could find only second level of validation, couldn't find json-schema validation in documentation. for example: lets say we have below sample json-schema:

```
{
"title": "Person",
"type": "object",
"properties": {
    "firstName": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "lastName": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "age": {
        "description": "Age in years",
        "type": "integer",
        "minimum": 0
    }
},
"required": ["firstName", "lastName"]
}
```

so how to validate this json-schema itself is valid or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a working example here with the [everit-org/json-schema](https://github.com/everit-org/json-schema) implementation (just in case you want to use a maintained library):
[How to validate a json schema against the version spec it specifies in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36075449/how-to-validate-a-json-schema-against-the-version-spec-it-specifies-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You have to validate schema against meta-schema: http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema