# JSON schema validator (linter) in Java or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am searching a JSON Schema validator (linter) in Java or Javascript from String. I want to validate only the JSON schema exactness (not simple JSON against the schema). The best would be to get back the line of errors.

I appreciate for any examples too.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Bests,
Rómeó Nagy

Comment: Solution found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36075449/how-to-validate-a-json-schema-against-the-version-spec-it-specifies-in-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to validate a json schema against the version spec it specifies in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36075449/how-to-validate-a-json-schema-against-the-version-spec-it-specifies-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Java: [Snow project](https://github.com/ssilverman/snowy-json#the-linter.). Supports draft-06, draft-07, 2019-09 versions. It may possible to add your own rules to the linter. But I dont know if it will be possible to add the 2020-12 rules.  Project contains the Linter class with the psvm main inside - you can use it as example. But it is under GNU AGPLv3 license, so your project should be open-sourced